# Convert CefRefPtr<CefV8Value> into int in Chromium Embedded Framework

Tags: c++, type-conversion, chromium-embedded

I'm trying to extend the `cefsimple` app that comes with the Chromium Embedded Framework to include a V8 handler. The code I've written looks like this so far;

```
bool SimpleHandler::Execute(const CefString& name,
            CefRefPtr<CefV8Value> object,
            const CefV8ValueList& arguments,
            CefRefPtr<CefV8Value>& retval,
            CefString& exception) {
    int argn = arguments.size();
    if (name == "serial_connect" && (argn == 4 || argn == 1))
    {
        if (connection.isOpen())
            connection.~Serial();
        connection = NULL;
        if (argn == 1)
        {
            int port = (arguments[0]); // convert to int?
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
    else if (name == "serial_send" && argn >= 1)
    {

    }
    else if (name == "serial_recieve")
    {

    }
    else
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

I'm having trouble converting the generic value object returned given by the handler into a cpp int that I can use in calculations. I've found the function `CefV8Value::GetIntValue();`, but I can't figure out how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try calling `object->GetIntValue()`

The reason is that CefRefPtr is an object that holds a reference to CefV8Value, so you need the arrow operator to access the underlying CefV8Value object it points to

Comment: `object` doesn't have a method by that name. Or any type of specific get method in fact; just `.get();`.

Comment: It should, but you may need to invoke it with `->` as in `object->GetIntValue()`